# UWP App WebUIApplication.onresuming not firing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, uwp, winjs, webui

I have a windows app using HTML/Javascript/Angular and when i minimise then maximise my onresuming does not fire.

My code setup is as follows

```
var winJSApp = WinJS.Application;

Windows.UI.WebUI.WebUIApplication.onresuming = function(eventArgs){
    console.log("Resuiming");
}
```

There is of course much more to it than this, but the onresuming function just doesnt do anything when i maximise.

I've tried to add event listeners to the WebupApplication.AddEventListener without any luck, and cannot work out how to get the onresuming to fire, when my app gains focus, after being "suspended" with a minimize

Answer (score 0):

> but the onresuming function just doesnt do anything when i maximise.

Why should maximise app trigger resuming event? How did you trigger the event?

I write the following code:

```
Windows.UI.WebUI.WebUIApplication.addEventListener("resuming", resumingHandler);

function resumingHandler() {
    console.log("Resuiming");
}
```

And it triggers without problem:
[image]